# MySQL Addition of Multiple Columns for Specific Entries

Tags: php, mysql, addition

I am trying to set up a web interface for recording tardies to classes and meetings through a MySQL database with a PHP front end. I have the database setup, but I can't figure out how to add all of the tardies up. In the database, there are 7 columns - one for each period in the day that I want to track tardies for (firstPeriodTardies, secondPeriodTardies, and so on). How can I add all of those up and display them on a page for a selected person in the DB?
So far, I have this:

```
$f12=mysql_query(SELECT firstPeriodTardy+secondPeriodTardy+thirdPeriodTardy+fourthPeriodTardy+fifthPeriodTardy+sixthPeriodTardy+seventhPeriodTardy AS LTOTAL FROM students WHERE ID = '$sID';) ?>
```

However, I don't know how to be able to do that for each person in the list. The list will be comprised of ~100 people that will each show up on the page. That part I can do, but not this part. What has got me in the WHERE ID= '$sID' ;). I'm assuming that it calling a specific entry that matches that ID, but I can't input each ID for each person manually. What should I try?

Thanks!

Edit: My DB is laid out like this: [DB Setup http://ubuntu.rossiv.com/stack-mysqldbtardy.png](http://ubuntu.rossiv.com/stack-mysqldbtardy.png)

Comment: sounds like you want to add "group by id"

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause.

```
SELECT firstPeriodTardy+secondPeriodTardy+...+seventhPeriodTardy AS LTOTAL 
FROM students 
GROUP BY ID
```

`GROUP BY [colname]` aggregates results (ie returns the result of the `SELECT ...` for *each* unique value in `[colname]`.

```
GROUP BY [colname]
<=>
for each value in unique(colname):
    SELECT xxxx
    WHERE [colname] = value
```

So in your case, it counts up the tardies, per unique `ID`.